# Magento set "please enquire for price" for product

Tags: magento

I have a magento site, and I want to set all the products prices, baskets and checkout screens to say "Please enquire for costs" instead of trying to display actual prices.

All payment is via purchase orders, so I dont need real prices on there, and people who enter a PO number (PO is the only payment option available) already know how much their purchases cost.

Is there a way I can do this without hacking all the templates?

Comment: I dare ["enquire"](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/inquire-vs-enquire/) if you're British...

Comment: Good link. Yes, in the sense of a casual "ask" rather than launch a formal investigation. But. Beside the point. Any actual solutions? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you need to change all template occurences of `price` accordingly.

The only way I can think of would be a type conversion in the product models from `decimal` to `string`, but that's an absolutely no go to me.

The products `price` attribute is involved in many calculation/sanitizing/validation processes of the Magento core modules and just would drive Magento to go nuts^^